# How to pass part of a two-dimensional array as parameter to a function?

Tags: c#

I've got a two-dimensional array like this:

```
double[,] results = new double[100,100];
```

I'd like to pass every one dimensional part of the array to a function as a paremeter.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
     cool_function (results[???], 10);
}
```

How do I do this in C#?

Comment: Your function only receive 1 parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[source](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WorkingWithArrays11232005064036AM/WorkingWithArrays.aspx) 
Jagged arrays are arrays of arrays. The elements of a jagged array are other arrays.

Declaring Jagged Arrays

Declaration of a jagged array involves two brackets. For example, the following code snippet declares a jagged array that has three items of an array.

```
int[][] intJaggedArray = new int[3][];
```

The following code snippet declares a jagged array that has two items of an array.

```
string[][] stringJaggedArray = new string[2][];
```

Initializing Jagged Arrays

Before a jagged array can be used, its items must be initialized. The following code snippet initializes a jagged array; the first item with an array of integers that has two integers, second item with an array of integers that has 4 integers, and a third item with an array of integers that has 6 integers.

```
// Initializing jagged arrays
intJaggedArray[0] = new int[2];
intJaggedArray[1] = new int[4];
intJaggedArray[2] = new int[6];
```

We can also initialize a jagged array's items by providing the values of the array's items. The following code snippet initializes item an array's items directly during the declaration.

```
// Initializing jagged arrays
intJaggedArray[0] = new int[2]{2, 12};
intJaggedArray[1] = new int[4]{4, 14, 24, 34};
intJaggedArray[2] = new int[6] {6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56 };
```

Comment: how is this answer considered as answer ??
Ricardo only give alternate version of array (Jaggadeg array instead of array) and very clear instruction on how to use it  yet missing the answer of how to use it as paramater which what the TS asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it without copying the corresponding part of the array.

Otherwise, you can use a `double[][]`. To initialize:

```
double[][] results = new double[100][];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    results[i] = new double[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean for an array *myarray[x][y]* that you want to call a function for *x* arrays of size *y* then all you need is the following code:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    cool_function(array[i], 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using a jagged array `Type[][]` instead of `Type[,]`. In this case you can just pass `array[index]`. Otherwise you will have to either pass the two-dimensional array together with the index of the subarray of interest and perform the indexing in the called method or create a copy of the subarray of interest.